# Issue pumping gas after using a gas can on 2017 pacifica

Tags: chrysler, fuel-tank

I used a gas can to fill my tank, it is a capless fuel filler. I was not aware that there was a funnel I should have used. Ever since doing this the fuel pump at the gas station cuts off as soon as gas starts flowing.

I believe I have gotten fuel down in my EVAP system and I am not sure how to troubleshoot this or  how to start taking this system apart.

I do not have any check engine light/code.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! On most "no cap" gas tanks, there are two folding caps which move out of the way and seal the tank. I'd bet the second one (the one inside of the filler neck, not the outer one) is stuck open or close. Either way it is causing a splash back on the nozzle and kicking the fuel off. You might want to check what it's doing, which should be able to be seen if you press the outer cap open and out of the way.

Comment: I can press both of them open. there is resistance like its on a spring. but they appear to close and open ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a piece of plastic in the filler neck. I removed the filler neck and could see a piece of plastic broke off and fellto the bottom blocking fuel from entering the tank causing the pump to shut off to prevent overflow.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).